# Robots.txt com espaços

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Eu criei um robots.txt e mapeei ele no meu host para ser encontrado na raiz, porém percebi que subi com espaços antes da barra, muitos espaços.

E como o processo de *deploy* é muito burocrático gostaria de saber se mesmo com os espaços os motores de busca irão entender a regra do arquivo?

Veja como ficou o arquivo.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:                                       /
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara, você descobre isso e outras coisas em relação a como o Google lê o robots.txt facilmente fazendo um teste pelo Search Console, no [Google Webmasters Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool?hl=pt-BR&siteUrl=http://seusite.com/).

Mas por via das dúvidas o melhor é apagar os espaços porque o Google pode conseguir ler, mas quem garante que todos os outros motores de busca também conseguem?